# Limit Mysql result when column value changes

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a query for getting all the multiple tags in my table

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from job_tags where tag_name in (
    select tag_name from job_tags group by tag_name having count(*) > 1
) ORDER BY tag_name");
```

I am getting result like this

```
 tag_id---tag_name



        5576----01-12-2015 
        5222----01-12-2015  
        5247----01-12-2015  
        6162----01-12-2015  
        6265----01-12-2015  
        5291----01-12-2015
        7159----B.Com
        7895----B.Com
        7692----B.Com
        8149----B.Com
        8289----B.Com
        8228----B.Com
        8045----B.Com
        8362----B.Com
        7793----B.Com
        5760----02-12-2015
        5030----02-12-2015
        5945----02-12-2015
        4703----02-12-2015
        5571----02-12-2015
        4580----02-12-2015
        4826----02-12-2015
        5593----02-12-2015
        5221----02-12-2015
        5478----02-12-2015
        5649----02-12-2015
        4867----02-12-2015
        6266----02-12-2015
        5292----02-12-2015
        5479----03-12-2015
        5220----03-12-2015
        5250----03-12-2015
        5899----03-12-2015
        5840----03-12-2015
        5293----03-12-2015
        5573----03-12-2015
        5575----03-12-2015
        5736----03-12-2015
    etc ....
```

I want to display only the multiples of first tag in first page and multiple of second tag in another page.

That is I want to limit the results exactly when the tag name changes (I have more than 6 thousand tags in my table)

Any Help is much appreciated

**EDIT -------**

***Expected output***

**first page**

```
5576----01-12-2015 
5222----01-12-2015  
5247----01-12-2015  
6162----01-12-2015  
6265----01-12-2015  
5291----01-12-2015
```

**second page**

```
        7159----B.Com
        7895----B.Com
        7692----B.Com
        8149----B.Com
        8289----B.Com
        8228----B.Com
        8045----B.Com
        8362----B.Com
        7793----B.Com
```

etc ..........

Comment: can you show the output you want

Comment: Sure .Can you please check my edit

Comment: Do you mean you want to display records with the same day per page?

Comment: @kael : Tags are not only dates .. I want to display all the same tags in one page

Answer (score 0):

You only need a condition to select the preferred tag_name. Therefore I used $tag_name in the query. Then you just need a script to determine the "right" tag name. With the operator 'LIKE' it is also possible to use wildcards like '%', e.g. to select all tags like you have done above already.

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"
select * from job_tags 
where tag_name in (
    select tag_name from job_tags group by tag_name having count(*) > 1)
and tag_name LIKE '$tag_name'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I have thousands of `$tag_name`and I want to limit the result when the tag name changes . This is not giving the output